# To show value of a variable inside <td></td> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable itotqty in my .cshtml file, which is declared as follows:

```
var itotqty = 0;      
itotqty = itotqty + item.TOT_QTY;
```

what I want is, I need to show it's value inside `<td></td>` tag.
I have tried below combinations:

```
<td style="text-align: center"><b> +itotqty.ToString()+ </b></td>
<td style="text-align: center"><b>' + itotqty.ToString() + '</b></td>
<td style="text-align: center"><b>"' + itotqty.ToString() + '"</b></td>
```

But showing that variable instead of its value while running the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we have to include both the declaration of `itotqty` and the expression in a `@{ }` block

```
@{
    var itotqty = 0;      
    itotqty = itotqty + item.TOT_QTY;
}
```

Then you can refer to this variable as `@itotqty`.

```
<td style="text-align: center"><b> +@itotqty.ToString()+ </b></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to present the variable in the `<td></td>` tag this way.

```
    <td style="text-align: center"><b> @(itotqty) </b></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert Var to string after,

```
 private string stritotqty;

            stritotqty = Convert.ToString(itotqty);
    public string itotqty { get { return stritotqty ; } }


    <td style="text-align: center"><b> <%=itotqty%></div> </b></td>
```

same as others,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Razor syntax. More about Razor C# Syntax read here:http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_syntax.asp

Your solution:

```
@{
var itotqty = 0;      
itotqty = itotqty + item.TOT_QTY;
}
```

then

```
<td style="text-align: center"><b>' + @itotqty.ToString() + '</b></td>
```

note, you have to use "@" when want to acces to variable you declared in c#